# method return type error in java

Tags: java, sum

I'm doing the "two sum" problem from Leetcode and I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that, given an array of integers and a target integer, checks to see if any pairs of integers within the array add up to the target. I realize it's not the most efficient algorithm but what I tried to do is to use a for loop that checks that the selected element isnt being added to itself, and then goes through all the pairs. This is my code:

```
package leetcodeproblem;

    public class Leet {

    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

        for(int i=nums[0];i<nums.length;i++){
            for(int x:nums){
                if (x!=i & (i+x)==target){
                    int i2 = java.util.Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(i);
                    int x2 = java.util.Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(x);
                    int[] answer = {i2,x2};

                    return answer;
                }else{
                    return nums;
               }
           }      
       }
   }
```

I keep getting this error: "This method must return a result of type int[]"

I thought I had both possibilities covered with the if/else statement, and that the function returns an int[] in both cases. Any ideas?

Comment: The loop will be skipped entirely if `nums[0] >= nums.length`. In any case, your code is definitely wrong, even if you can make it compile.

Comment: Thanks, how about a hint as to why it's wrong?

Comment: Not really. You haven't clearly defined the problem you're solving, but it's hard to see how your code would solve it by any interpretation. One glaring problem is that your loops don't loop because you're always returning inside.

Comment: The problem is I have to return the pairs of numbers within the array nums that add up to the target. What do you mean by returning inside?

Comment: If for loop is skipped there is no return statement

Comment: You have an if/else inside your inner loop. One or the other *must* execute immediately. In either case, the method will return on the spot, so your loops never loop. Also, you might want to try using more explicit variable names. Can you define in English what `i` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java compiler thinks that it is possible that loops won't execute (For example it nums[0] is bigger than the length) . In that case your method won't call a return. So you have to put a return at the end.

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

    for(int i=nums[0];i<nums.length;i++){
           for(int x:nums){
               if (x!=i & (i+x)==target){
                  int i2 = java.util.Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(i);
                  int x2 = java.util.Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(x);
                  int[] answer = {i2,x2};

                  return answer;

               }else{
                   return nums;
               }


           }

       }

       return nums; //or whatever you want (maybe null, or an empty array)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

What if `nums[0]` is `2`  and `nums.length = 1`?

The loop never run because `i < nums.length` will be false, so there is no return statement at the end. Just add a `return nums;` before the last curly brace and it will compile

Comment: Sorry could you explain this a little more? I don't see why the for-loop wouldn't run in that case.

Comment: What? Then it would be true because `i < nums.length`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that the for loop won't run even once then none of the return statement will be executed so outside the for loop write a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop has the chance of not running therefore nothing would be returned in the method. Add a `return null;` after the for loop.

Comment: @Sreemat Primitive arrays are objects and can be assigned null.

Comment: @Sreemat `int[]` is not a primitive type.

Comment: @shmosel sorry my mistake